# Keeping multiple bookmarks when filling form

Tags: vba, ms-word, userform, bookmarks

I'm trying to create a userform that will add text to the Word document based on a mixture of inputs coming from the userform. It could be checkboxes, lists, or textboxes where one writes content. As I was looking around for codes to preserve the bookmarks that I use to transfer the inputs into Word text, I came across one that allowed me to successfully preserve the bookmark for future editing. I thought I could use the same method for multiple bookmarks, but it seems not to work. With an example, now.

I have TextBox1, TextBox2 (in the userform), Bookmark1, Bookmark2 (in the Word document), and CommandButton1 to give the ok to transfer info from the userform to the Word document. I want to make TextBox1's content appear where Bookmark1 is, and TextBox2's content where Bookmark2 is. Code I tried is:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim BMRange01 As Range
Set BMRange01 = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Bookmark1").Range
BMRange01.Text = Me.TextBox1.Value
ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Add "Bookmark1", BMRange01

Dim BMRange02 As Range
Set BMRange02 = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Bookmark2").Range
BMRange02.Text = Me.TextBox2.Value
ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Add "Bookmark2", BMRange02

End Sub
```

When I tried with a single bookmark (from the first "Dim" to the last BMRange01) it worked just fine, and I could edit and re-use the bookmark multiple times. When I try with two of them, however, only one of them is preserved (or rather, deleted and created back again). Specifically, the second one seems to be preserved, while the first one (Bookmark1) is deleted.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code that you have posted here. It works exactly as intended.

Comment: If working with modern documents, use Content Controls. It is easier. See http://www.gmayor.com/Userform.htm

Answer (score 0):

Make your life a bit easier and create a separate sub to handle the work. Eg:

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    ReplaceBookmarkText ActiveDocument, "Boomark1", me.TextBox1.Value
    ReplaceBookmarkText ActiveDocument, "Boomark2", me.TextBox2.Value
End Sub

Sub ReplaceBookMarkText(doc As Document, bmName As String, txt)
   Dim rng As Range
   Set rng = doc.Bookmarks(bmName).Range
   rng.Text = txt
   doc.Bookmarks.Add bmName, rng
End Sub
```